# Javascript alert box unblock on Mozilla

Tags: javascript

I have blocked Javascript alert messages on my Mozilla browser and now I want to turn them back on, but I can't figure out how. Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Have you closed and opened your browser?

Comment: how did you block the alerts?

Comment: @ W.D - Yes tried closing and opening but it did not help.

Comment: Go to settings restore default. That works for everything I guess.

Comment: @ Dr.Molle - when alert appears many times browser gives you an option(checkbox at the bottom of the alert message) to stop messages from showing. I checked that checkbox and now I don't get any alerts from that site, the problem is I need to see them.

Comment: @K.I What about clearing the cache (although I doubt it will work, but give it a try)?

Comment: @ sanki - I am looking for a solution without having to restore to default, but will go back to this if that solution cannot be found. Thanks.

Comment: @  W.D - tried clearing the cache didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: @K.I I have just tried what you have described (checked the checkbox to remove further `alerts`) and closed the tab opened another one with the same page and the `alerts()` have appeared. You may try what @sanki suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on webpage > select View Page Info entry > select Permissions tab >
modify Show Notifications or Open Popup Window items to suit.

Answer (score 0):

In modern Firefox the block is set for the current tab session.
**So the easiest way is reopen the page in a new tab.**

Note that closing and reopening tab restores its state and session, so it won't help!
You need to open new tab (or window).

**Bonus tip:** grab and drag the lock icon in the address bar and drop it next to current tab.
That will reopen current page in a new tab (and it will even use the same Firefox Container, if you use one).